# How to dispose of resources safely in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, dispose

Just like in visual studio WinForms. I first close any connections before exiting the application. Otherwise, the application will still run in the background. I do this by clicking on the form itself and then click on the closeBeforeexiting property.

I then close all of my connection just before the application exits.

My question is then, how do I do this in an android studio? I want to close of a RFID class first before exiting the app. The reason for this is another app on the device that uses the same RFID class. But since the RFID class did not close safely and is still running in the background, the other application crashes because it cannot access this class.

Is there a closeBeforeexit property in android studio, perhaps in the res->layout->content_main.xml that provides me with the same functionality as in visual studio

I could do this using an exit button on the application but I see people generally use the back button that is already on the screen to exit the application. Is there any way I can access this back button and put my close connection function in there?

**Answer:**

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
    try {
        RFIDReader reader = RFID.open();
        reader.stop();
        reader.close();
        super.onBackPressed();
        return;
    }
    catch (ReaderException e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Error: " + e, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can intercept the back button and do anything you want there (even cancel the back navigation), but then you'll miss the cases where the user leaves by the Home button, or an incoming call, or through a notification...

What you should do instead is to override the `onPause`, `onStop`, and/or, `onDestroy` methods for your activity. They are all callbacks related to the activity life cycle, which you will soon need to learn about.

In short: `onPause` happens when you lose focus, `onStop` when you're no longer visible, and `onDestroy` when the activity is fully deleted (e.g. the user pressed "back", but usually not when they pressed "home").

In your case, `onStop` is probably the most suitable one.

Comment: I am trying to use CTRL+Alt to pull up these methods but it is not showning. Type each one by hand is tiring :(. How do I pull up all these methods quicker?

Comment: `ALT + insert` - override methods.

Answer (score 0):

> My question is then, how do I do this in an android studio? I want to
> close of a RFID class first before exiting the app. The reason for
> this is another app on the device that uses the same RFID class. But
> since the RFID class did not close safely and is still running in the
> background, the other application crashes because it cannot access
> this class.

You better read -> [**Understand the Activity Lifecycle**](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle) to see how Android works with Activities and background tasks. If you're running the task in a background task, you should be able to close the RFID using `close()` method.

> I could do this using an exit button on the application but I see
> people generally use the back button that is already on the screen to
> exit the application. Is there any way I can access this back button
> and put my close conection funstion in there?

Using [`onBackPressed()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#onBackPressed()) method should help in your case. Keep in mind that [`finish()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#finish()) method is not a good approach to close the `Activity`.

> Is there a closeBeforeexit property in android studio, perhaps in the
> res->layout->content_main.xml that provides me with the same
> functionality as in visual studio

`layout->content_main.xml` is the UI layout in Android and to be able to handle such things, you'll need to go with java or Kotlin.